# Running Spring Boot Microservices using Docker and AWS ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, spring-boot, amazon-ecs

I am developing a simple micro-service based application using Spring Boot, Kafka & MongoDB.

There are 4 Spring Boot based REST services that performs CRUD on MongoDB(shared between all services for now) and publish/poll messages to/from Kafka cluster.

Currently I have them all deployed on hand crafted AWS EC2 instances. Kafka/Zookeeper has 3 brokers/instances. MongoDb with no replication/sharding.

**What do I want to achieve ?**

- Run the micro-services in docker containers managed by ECS.
- Ability to scale out these services.
- Ability to create dedicated environment(DEV, QA, UAT, PROD) on ECS.
- Run Kafka and MongoDB cluster with replication and sharding as containers managed by ECS.

I am fairly new to Docker & ECS concepts as such and not able to find exactly how is it done. I am able to create Dockerfile, image and push to docker hub and use one of the service ( that has no external dependencies ) on ECS. One of the Dockerfile looks like this:-

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
EXPOSE 443 443
LABEL "author":"Kumar Sambhav Jain"
COPY build/distributions/app.tar /opt/app/
RUN tar -xvf /opt/app/admin.tar -C /opt/app/
WORKDIR /opt/app/admin/bin
ENTRYPOINT ["./admin"]
```

**Questions:-**

1. What is ideal or right way to deploy the whole application ? Do I need ECS cluster per environment (DEV, QA, UAT) or ECS cluster per service type - two services need to be publicly exposed on port 443/80.
2. How do the service connect to MongoDB and Kafka running in containers ? Currently Kafka broker and mongo connection are maintained in application.yml files like this:-

> ```
> spring:
>   data:
>     mongodb:
>       host: 172.31.18.25
>       database: abcd
>       username: test
>       password: abcd@123
>   cloud:
>     stream:
>       kafka:
>         binder:
>           zk-nodes:
>           - 172.31.18.58:2181
>           - 172.31.28.201:2181
>           - 172.31.25.60:2181
>           brokers:
>           - 172.31.18.58:9092
>           - 172.31.28.201:9092
>           - 172.31.25.60:9092
> ```

How does it change once everything is containerized ?

Reference to any study material on this exact topic.

Comment: Hi buddy! Any news on this that you can share ? 
I starting with a similar architecture based on docker in ecs.